# How to write a short, and persuasive headline?

Tags: style, creative-writing, technique, structure, word-choice

I have the following sentence that I am thinking of using as headline `

> Shop online. Locally.

`

However, I am not sure if this headline connects well with it sub-headline.

> Pick up the goods you can't get anywhere else in the places you go
>   everyday.

Hence, my question is, is the headline clear, grammar-free, persuasive, and does it connect well with its follow-up sentence, the subheadline.

Thanks in advance, and for any clarification, let me know.

Comment: A headline is attractive, not persuasive

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **this is really good.** If I were to see this headline, I'd like it. It's good because it tells me what it's about - online shopping - before going into the subheading gives me a bit of extra detail. Your grammar is absolutely fine. I wouldn't call this *persuasive* though, as headlines aren't meant to persuade, **they are made to attract.**

Considering you asked in the title how to write a short and good headline, I'd like to point this out. Humans *love* groups of three, it's a magic number in the world of advertising. I bet if you watched a random advert you'd see some *triadic structure* (use of that magic number three). To use triadic structure and improve your headline, you could try something like:

> Shop online. Quickly. Easily.

This also uses two adverbs with connotations of convenience.

I hope this helped you :)